# GDB + TUI + GNU Screen - sending gdb output to different screen

Tags: c, linux, gdb, gnu-screen, tui

I'm running GNU Screen and gdb with TUI, and I'm having some issues relating to scrollback, so I want to send the output to a different screen window. What's the best way to do this?

Ideally i'd want the tui input and output (i.e. anything I do like 'print ' from gdb) to be on one window, and the output from printf's, etc to be on a different screen window.

Does anyone know how to do this?

(I'm actually doing remote debugging over gdb + serial, so it's connecting via target remote /dev/ttyS0 in my ~/.gbdinit).

Comment: Maybe redirect program's output (`run ... > output_file`) and do `tail -F output_file` on the other screen to read it?

Answer (score 0):

There are maybe a few ways to do this.  I think the simplest is the "tty" command though.  See "help tty".

Another approach is that taken by "screenify" -- use gdb's inferior call functionality to change the controlling tty (and various std* file descriptors) of the program.

Another approach is to just run your program in another tty and then use "attach".

Comment: Could you help walk me through this? I don't quite understand. I've been looking on this page (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Input_002fOutput.html) but I don't really follow what I'm supposed to do. 

In my gdb prompt, I see "(gdb) show inferior-tty. Terminal for future runs of program being debugged is ""." 


Running 'tty' from the other screen window gives me '/dev/pts/11'.

Doesn't setting tty change where I INPUT data from, too?